# Typing problems

Tags: python, recursion

Hi I have binary tree and 2 functions to operate with him but I when I run mypy --disallow-any-explicit --strict I always get errors that I have no idea how to fix

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value: str,
                 left: Optional['Tree'] = None,
                 right: Optional['Tree'] = None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def to_rpn(tree: Tree) -> str:
    result = ""
    if tree.value != "+" and tree.value != "*":
        return result + tree.value
    return result + (to_rpn(tree.left) + " ") + (to_rpn(tree.right) + " ") + tree.value #*

def evaluate(tree: Tree) -> int:
    if tree.value == "+":
        return int(evaluate(tree.left)) + int(evaluate(tree.right)) #*
    elif tree.value == "*":
        return int(evaluate(tree.left)) * int(evaluate(tree.right)) #*
    else:
        return int(tree.value)
```

- = Argument 1 "to to_rpn"/"evaluate" has incompatible type "Optional[Tree]"; expected "Tree"
  (errow which i get when i run mypy on it)

I would be really grateful for any help because I spend the last 2 hours trying to solve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are representing the empty tree with `None`, so your functions have to accept an `Optional[Tree]` argument as well.

```
def to_rpn(tree: Optional[Tree]) -> str:
    ...

def evaluate(tree: Optional[Tree]) -> int:
    ...
```

Comment: this doesn't work it was first thing i have tried then i have error                                           
 Item "None" of "Optional[Tree]" has no attribute "value"

Comment: Just because your function *accepts* a `None` value doesn't mean it's prepared to *use* it.

Comment: `to_rpn` should return the empty string if the argument is `None`; it's not clear if `evaluate` has a sensible default to return for an empty tree.

Comment: You have to modify your code to do this right thing if `tree == None`.  What do you want `to_rpn` to do in that case?  Right now, it will fail.  MyPy is correctly warning you that there is a bug in your code.